# How can I scrape remote jobs on Stack Overflow Jobs with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Dear fellow software engineers,

I have problems with scraping remote jobs on Stack Overflow Jobs. I have googled for a solution and have studied parts of the Scrapy documentation, but I haven't found the solution to my problems.

**My goal is to scrape remote jobs on Stack Overflow Jobs.**

Here are the fields that I want to get for each remote job:

- Job title
- Salary range (if present)
- Job type
- Experience level
- Role
- Industry (if present)
- Company size (if present)
- Company type (if present)
- Preferred timezone (if present)
- Technologies

I have tried doing this with 2 different spiders. Below is each one of them with brief explanation:

The first spider I wrote mimicked the URL structure I have in my browser as I browse remote jobs. For example, if I'm on the third page of the remote jobs listings, I get the URL that looks like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=522484&pg=3&r=true I mimicked that URL structure in my spider.

Here's the code for that spider:

```
import scrapy
import time

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs"
    ]
    already_visited_links = []

    def parse(self, response, page_number=0): # 0 is a magic number for an invalid page number
        jobs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'job')]")
        links_to_next_pages = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 's-pagination--item')]").css("a::attr(href)").getall()

        # visit each job page (as I do in the browser) and scrape the relevant information (Job title etc.)
        for job in jobs:
            # get the job ID for each job
            job_id = int(job.xpath('@data-jobid').extract_first()) # there will always be one element
            # now visit the link with the job_id and get the info
            if page_number != 0:
                job_link_to_visit = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=" + str(job_id) + "&r=true" + "&p=" + str(page_number)
            else:
                job_link_to_visit = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?id=" + str(job_id) + "&r=true"
            request = scrapy.Request(job_link_to_visit,
                             callback=self.parse_job)
            yield request

        # go to the next job listings page (if you haven't already been there)
        # not sure if this solution is the best since it has a loop which has a recursion in it
        for link_to_next_page in links_to_next_pages:
            if link_to_next_page not in self.already_visited_links:
                self.already_visited_links.append(link_to_next_page)
                next_page_number = 0
                # below is a pattern I noticed: whenever a link has a p in its GET request, it is always near the end
                # therefore, here I check if the last thing in the link is "p=<someNumber>" and if it is
                # then I get <someNumber>; I know this is not robust, but I currently can't think of a better way to do this
                if link_to_next_page[-4] == "p":
                    next_page_number = int(link_to_next_page[-1])
                if link_to_next_page[-5] == "p":
                    next_page_number = int(link_to_next_page[-2:])
                yield response.follow(link_to_next_page, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={"page_number" : next_page_number})

        print("End of parse method")

    def parse_job(self, response):
        with open("dump.txt", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

However, the `parse_job` method of the above code produced a `dump.txt` file which doesn't match the contents of the website I saw in my web browser.

The approach for my 2nd spider was to visit the job details page directly, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/522636, but that didn't work as well. The contents of the webpage being scraped in my web browser and the contents of the **dump.txt** file differ. Here's the code for that spider:

```
import scrapy
import time

class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobs"
    start_urls = [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/remote-developer-jobs"
    ]
    already_visited_links = []

    def parse(self, response):
        jobs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'job')]")
        links_to_next_pages = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 's-pagination--item')]").css("a::attr(href)").getall()

        # visit each job page (as I do in the browser) and scrape the relevant information (Job title etc.)
        for job in jobs:
            # get the job ID for each job
            job_id = int(job.xpath('@data-jobid').extract_first()) # there will always be one element
            # now visit the link with the job_id and get the info
            job_link_to_visit = "https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/" + str(job_id)
            request = scrapy.Request(job_link_to_visit,
                             callback=self.parse_job)
            yield request

        # go to the next job listings page (if you haven't already been there)
        # not sure if this solution is the best since it has a loop which has a recursion in it
        for link_to_next_page in links_to_next_pages:
            if link_to_next_page not in self.already_visited_links:
                self.already_visited_links.append(link_to_next_page)
                yield response.follow(link_to_next_page, callback=self.parse)

        print("End of parse method")

    def parse_job(self, response):
        with open("dump.txt", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

From my understanding, I think that my problem stems from the fact that there's some JavaScript and/or AJAX here that somehow makes the server know that my spider is indeed a spider. Again, I have looked around, but failed to find the solution to my problems.

**Can someone tell me how can I build a spider that scrapes the information I want to scrape from remote jobs on Stack Overflow Jobs?**

Thank you!

Comment: One thing to check is on any webpage you can right-click and view the page source of it. If data is available there then only you can get it through XPath, CSS selector techniques. Otherwise, you need to check API/JS requests where the data is coming from.